# 94 Dodge Ram starts and runs shortly, then shuts down; first happened while driving

Tags: maintenance, dodge, stall, ram

Recently, I was driving my truck down the interstate going 55mph when my 
acceleration stopped as I had my foot on the gas. I had half a tank of gas, 
battery strong. I pulled over and was able to start it again but then died again 
several seconds later or if put into drive.

I've towed it back to my house and it still cranks and runs for several seconds then dies.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

If your truck is EFI and not carbureted, turn your ignition on without starting your vehicle.  Listen for your fuel pump to start for a few seconds and then stop.  After one or two times of turning on the ignition and you do not hear the hum of your fuel pump starting and stopping.  Try replacing your fuel pump.

Comment: I agree with your assessment of it possibly being a fuel pump. The 94 I believe should be FI. To really understand if it's the fuel pump, the OP should use a fuel pressure tester while it's running to see what's going on. If fuel pressure drops right after startup (or minimal fuel pressure is there to begin with), they'll need a new pump. Obviously they are getting *some fuel pressure* or it wouldn't be starting up at all.